# Ionic2 AppPreferences undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I have the following code to get the city from Ionic2 native AppPreferences:

```
import { AppPreferences } from '@ionic-native/app-preferences';

constructor(public appPreferences: AppPreferences) {
    
    console.log("The city is : " + this.loadPreferences("selectedCity"));
   
}

loadPreferences(preferenceKey: any){
    this.appPreferences.fetch(preferenceKey).then((res) => { return res; });
}
```

Inside `.then((res) => {console.log});` the value is printed and works fine. But when I return the value or assign it to some variable then I get the value "The city is: undefined". Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: The fetch method is asynchronous and only runs way after the constructor is done. Can you give a code example to what fails? Is this the code you are trying to run?

Comment: Yes this is the actual code which I am trying to run

Comment: Think about each line of code and WHEN it is executed

Comment: I got it. As @misha130 said think about each line. The following line is printed before I get the result from async method:
    console.log("The city is : " + this.loadPreferences("selectedCity"));

I changed my code a little bit. Now I run my code when I get the result in async function. Thanks alot

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an Observable/http/async call in angular2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43055706/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-observable-http-async-call-in-angular2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it. As @misha130 said think about each line. The following line is printed before I get the result from async method:

```
console.log("The city is : " + this.loadPreferences("selectedCity"));
```

I changed my code a little bit. Now I run my code when I get the result in async function. Thanks a lot